# How to loop nested switch statement correctly to provide output shown?

Tags: c

Need code that will repeat prompt `Enter value(1,2,e):` every time.

- After input `1`, it should do `case 1` action and repeat prompt.
- After input `2`, it should do `case 2` action and repeat prompt.
- After input other than `1,2,e`, it should print `"try again"` and repeat prompt.
- After input `e`, it should print `"exit program"` and end.

**Error:**

If I enter a character, the loop is infinite... how do i fix this?

I've tried a `switch statement` in a while loop as shown below.

```
int main() {
    int value;
    printf("%s", "Enter value(1,2,e):");
    scanf_s("%d", &value);

    while (value != 'e') {
        switch (value) {
        case 1:
            printf("You have picked correctly!");
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("You have picked incorrectly!");
            break;

        default:
            printf("try again.");
        }
        printf("%s", "\nEnter value(1,2,e):");
        scanf_s("%d", &value);
    } printf("Exit program");
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

I want my output to be:

```
Enter value(1,2,e):1 You have picked correctly!
Enter value(1,2,e):2 You have picked incorrectly!
Enter value(1,2,e):3 Try again!
Enter value(1,2,e):e Bye!
*exits program*
```

Comment: Think about how `getchar()` works. If I type `1<enter>` how many characters are in the input buffer for you to get? What is the observed incorrect behavior in this program?

Comment: Must turn off canonical mode first or input will be buffered. You can just use fgets or gets and switch first element of array.

Comment: scanf_s() ? What is this?

Comment: scanf_s() is same as scanf()

Comment: `scanf_s` has a return value that's very helpful to validate that you scanned the number of values you hoped for. You should use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for letters, you have to allow the user to enter letters:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[81];
    int value;

    while (1) {
        printf("%s", "Enter value(1,2,e):");
        scanf("%s", buffer);
        if ('e' == buffer[0]) {
            break;
        }
        value = atoi(buffer);
        switch (value) {
            case 1:
                printf("You have picked correctly!\n");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("You have picked incorrectly!\n");
                break;

            default:
                printf("try again.\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Exit program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**

This program does no error checking. This code should not be used in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

To simply this we can just read `value` as char instead of integer, so  that we can input anything i.e number or characters if and only if you would like to have options "0 to 9"
in switch case(below program modified to use chars), if cases are more than 0..9 then program give by @David Cullen is the way.

```
int main() {
char value;
printf("%s", "Enter value(1,2,e):");
scanf_s("%c", &value);

while (value != 'e') {

switch (value) {
case '1':
    printf("You have picked correctly!");
    break;

case '2':
    printf("You have picked incorrectly!");
    break;

default:
    printf("try again.");

}
printf("%s", "\nEnter value(1,2,e):");
scanf_s("%c", &value);
} 
 printf("Exit program");
 getchar();
 getchar();
}
```

Comment: Did you compile and run this program? I don't think it does what you think it does.

Comment: I did, i have seen this kind of program in production as well, it works well since we can read number as char(it uses ASCII values of chars 0=48, .... 9=57 when we enclose number with ' ' in switch, even we can replace `case '1':` with `case 49:` it works fine  as i verified)

Comment: I just ran your code again, and the newline gets read as a character, causing the "try again" message to be printed.